# High speed matrix manipulation in c#?

Tags: c#, image, math

I'm working on some image manipulation code in c# and need to do some matrix operations (specifically 2D convolution).  I have the code written in matlab which uses the `conv2` function ... is there a library for C# / .NET that does good high-speed matrix manipulations?  I'd be fine if it requires some specific GPU and does the matrix math on-GPU if that's what it takes.

Comment: You really ought to retitle this as "image" instead of "matrix"

Comment: @Victor Liu: He is asking for a matrix math library. The matrices are used in the convolution process. An image is the target of the convolution.

Comment: Yeah, the end use may be for image manipulation, but in general it's a math library.  For the processing I'm doing an image is just a really big matrix.

Comment: I generally take "matrix" to mean the mathematical object (rank 2 tensor). The function `conv2` works on 2D arrays, which lacks the mathematical structure of a matrix. I was prepared to recommend something like LAPACK when I saw the thread title.

Comment: I'm not a MatLab user....does conv2 return a matrix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a nice C# port of OpenCV. I'm not sure about your convolution speicifically, but from [this link](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/b72c032d-59ae-c36f-5e00-12f8d621dfb8.htm) it appears likely.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea would be to create a dll with your routines that you link to with C#. I think Matlab has export/compile to C file functionality..

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/

Answer (score 1):

For GPU based work have a look at CUDA :

http://www.nvidia.com/object/what_is_cuda_new.html

.Net with CUDA :

http://www.hoopoe-cloud.com/Solutions/CUDA.NET/Default.aspx

Comment: What would you recommend for OpenCL and .NET?

Comment: I only gave OpenCL an informational scan..Nvidia hardware was mandated..sorry.

Out of curiosity..how many iterations against what image size are you doing ? I spend some time doing deconvolution on astronomical images and a run of ~20 iterations on a 4096 x 4096 32bpp image only takes a few minutes on a dual core box without using the GPU.